# Animate many divs with one script (only animate the selected one)

Tags: jquery

Hello guys im trying create a script that can animate a div 
the problem is that i want to use  this script on many divs and animate the selected one

here is the jquery script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.window_content').mouseleave(function() {
            $('.theme_window').animate({'right': '+=297px'},'fast');
        });
        $('.theme_window').mouseover(function() {
            $('.theme_window').animate({'right': '-=297px'},'fast');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here are the divs

```
<div class="window">
    <div class="window_content">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="theme_window">
        Sport
    </div>
</div>
<div class="window">
    <div class="window_content">
    Content
    </div>
    <div class="theme_window" style="background-color:#1372BF">
       Music
    </div>
</div>
```

I only showed 2 divs with the class="window" but will have many divs

I know my script dont work as good as i want, when i select one div all the other divs are animated.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VyqwB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many ways to get this..

using siblings()

```
 $(this).siblings('.theme_window').animate({'right': '+=297px'},'fast');
```

using find()

```
$(this).parent().find('.theme_window').animate({'right': '+=297px'},'fast');
```

using next()

```
$(this).next('.theme_window').animate({'right': '+=297px'},'fast');
```

but the most important thing here is `$(this)` instance(reference)..`

`$('.theme_window')` -> this selects all elements with class theme_window so all your elements was getting animated..

with `$(this).next(`.theme_window`)` , now the browser knows it is just, the next element of current selected element whose class is theme_window , thus animating that particular element only.

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of `this`

```
$(this).next('.theme_window').animate({'right': '+=297px'},'fast');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` object which points the object calling that event

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.window_content').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).siblings(".theme_window").animate({'right': '+=297px'},'fast');
        });
        $('.theme_window').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).animate({'right': '-=297px'},'fast');
        });
    });
```